# Tuning JVM Args for CloudBees App

Tags: java, performance, cloudbees, jvm-arguments, paas

I just read the CloudBees [developer doc on adjusting PermGen](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/JVM+PermGen%20Space) but was wondering if they offer anything else for tuning heap, GC and the JVM in general.

I usually tune my Tomcat apps extensively and would like to deploy my apps to Tomcat instances with the most performant JVM args possible.

Comment: In that case I suggest you investigate how your application behaves.  There is no one size fits all options.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - he's saying that he wants to ship his web app with specific JVM args that are already customized for his app.

Comment: @IAmYourFaja In that case, his question is really about configuring `tomcat` to do this.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Iamyourfaja is right - you aren't reading my question. I'm asking how to make sure that the Tomcat instances running on the CloudBees PaaS *receive* the JVM args I've specifically tuned for my app. So it's not about Tomcat, it's not about "how to tune JVM args", it's about how to make sure my CloudBees/Tomcat app uses the JVM args I've tuned for it ahead of time.

Comment: The best way to have the JVM parameters set correctly is to document how you should configure the system.  You can't change the JVM args after a program has started.  Even if it were possible to do what you suggest, I don't believe it would be a good idea as each application is different and setting these parameters incorrectly is worse than not setting them at all.

Comment: Okay still don't think I'm explaining this correctly, but it's very simple: I have a web application (WAR) that deploys to Tomcat. CloudBees allows you to deploy your WARs to *their* Tomcat instances. CloudBees allows you - via `cloudbees-web.xml` or their command-line tool - to configure the size of each Tomcat instance's `PermGen`. I am asking if they *also* allow your to configure *other* JVM arguments, besides `PermGen` size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JVM parms can be passed using JAVA_OPTS. See https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Java+Container. For example:

```
bees app:deploy -a app_id -R JAVA_OPTS="<parm>=<value>"
```